# Monte Carlo (MC) dropout in Keras with R

Tags: r, keras, montecarlo, conv-neural-network, dropout

How to implement Monte Carlo dropout with Keras in Convolutional neural networks to estimate predictive uncertainty as suggested by YARIN GAL? I am using R.[R-Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juMhn.png)

I am fitting the model in small batches and want to evaluate the model in small batches as well with Monte Carlo dropout.Could not find any hint in Keras documentation.BTW, I trained my model with flag training=TRUE.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone has a pythonic implementation for this one?

Comment: @Haramoz did you see my answer? :)

Comment: yes I realized later and upvoted already. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular dropout only drops neurons randomly at training time, not a test time, so this is the default behavior of the `Dropout` class. If you want MC dropout, you need to use `training=TRUE` at test time as well, and you must run the forward pass multiple times: this will give you a distribution of predictions, which you can use as you please, for example to compute the mean.

I'm not familiar enough with R, so here is the class I use instead of the standard `Dropout` class:

```
class MCDropout(keras.layers.Dropout):
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        return super(MCDropout, self).call(inputs, training=True)
```